# What does "setOriginAddress()" does to sales order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales

I have seen this function in code,
i am assuming it is used to "**Set origin address for shipping rate estimation**"

I am not much, its used for what purpose & why it takes/sets "`System > Configuration > Shipping Settings > Origin`" in request.

Any guidance, if anybody knows its better ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow the magneto guidelines to understand.**

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/point-of-origin.html